# Counting the instances of a duplicate value after using groupby for a column

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working on a dataset that looks like this:

```
col1
person1  gene1
person1  gene1
person1  gene2
person1  gene3
person1  gene4
person2  gene1
person2  gene2
person2  gene3
person2  gene4
person3  gene1

person3  gene1
person3  gene1
person3  gene2
person3  gene3
person3  gene3
person3  gene4
```

For each person, I want to count the number of times a gene appears more than once.

For example, in the case I presented above, person1 has gene1 duplicated, person2 has no genes duplicated, and person3 has gene1 and gene3 duplicated.  Thus, I would want my code to output 3.

I know that there is a duplicated pandas code:
DataFrame.duplicated(subset=None, keep='first')

However, trying to apply it to my dataframe, I keep getting told I need to apply it?

Thanks

I added a clarification for additional help:

```
person1 gene1
person1 gene1
person1 gene2
person1 gene2
person2 gene1
person2 gene1
person3 gene1
person3 gene1
person3 gene2
person3 gene2
person3 gene2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do with `size`

```
df.groupby([*df.columns]).size().gt(1).sum()
Out[37]: 3
```

Comment: Thanks, that works perfectly.  What if I wanted to only report if an individual has more than one duplicated gene?  So for example, in this case, only person3 has two duplicates.  Would I change .gt(1) to get(2)?

Comment: @SteveStevemanMan `df.groupby([*df.columns]).size().gt(1).any(level=0).sum()
`

Comment: During a manual curation of my dataset, using .size() and .sum() gave me the wrong values (it's giving me a much higher value.)  I think I explained it wrong to you however, my mistake. In this second scenario, I only want to report if an individual has at least two duplicates.  So person3 has two genes with duplicates, so we'd report this as 1.  I'v been playing around with .count() and some other functions, but to no avail.

Comment: Yeah my bad.  I get this might beyond the scope of stackoverflow for this much help, but I added an example dataset to the original problem for clarification: In that example,

Person1 has gene1 and gene2 showing up twice.  Person2 has only gene1 showing up twice. Person 3 has gene1 showing up twice, and gene3 showing up three times.  So the output would be 2.

Comment: @SteveStevemanMan can you explain more like why this result 2 not 4  or 3

Comment: Sure.  So in this second situation, I want to look into the individuals who have multiple genes being duplicated. I don't care for the individuals who have only one gene duplicated (So I don't care about person2.) And then I want to count the number of times that these weird occurrences happen before I investigate them.

Comment: @SteveStevemanMan `df.groupby([*df.columns]).size().gt(1).sum(level=0).gt(1).sum()
`